# Radio Button Animation not working when adding Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a group of radio buttons and also have the animation work. You will see if I delete the `<div>` with `class="group55"`  from the code, then the animation works just fine. When I add that element back in, it seems like the CSS I have is not being recognized any longer. What am I doing wrong? The ultimate goal would be to have the "group55" `<div>` surround the group of radio buttons and still have the animation keep working.

```css
.toggle1:checked ~ .panel1 {
  left: 0px;
}

.panel1 {
  transition:all 500ms ease;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: -300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group55">
<input type="radio" class="toggle1" id="toggle1" name="group" checked/>
<input type="radio" class="toggle2" id="toggle2" name="group" />


<div class="panel1">
panels 1
</div>
```

(Also available at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85f57nd8/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not work because you need to put the panel as sibling of the input, to make the sibling selector (~) work.

**Fix HTML:**

```
<div class="group55">
<input type="radio" class="toggle1" id="toggle1" name="group" checked />
<input type="radio" class="toggle2" id="toggle2" name="group" />
    <div class="panel1">
panels 1
</div>
</div>
```

**Check:** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/85f57nd8/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you try to add  the "group55"  surround the group of radio buttons,your animation will not work.Click here to see you code again [the code that you wish to do](https://jsfiddle.net/85f57nd8/9/)
Because the class ".toggle1:checked ~ .panel1" will only work when the ".toggle1" is checked and both ".toggle1" class and ".panel1" class must have inside the "group55"  like this.....

```
<div class="group55">
<input type="radio" class="toggle1" id="toggle1" name="group" checked />
<input type="radio" class="toggle2" id="toggle2" name="group" />
<div class="panel1">
panels 1
</div>
</div>
```

[Click here to see the answer with another way](https://jsfiddle.net/85f57nd8/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Something i also did was setting the left property of your panel 1 class to 4px and it worked, because in css properties like left and right work in opposite way so when you said left -300px it's actually the left but normally it ought to go right. Check http://jsfiddle.net/85f57nd8/4/

```css
.toggle1:checked ~ .panel1 {
left: 0px;
}

.panel1 {
transition:all 500ms ease;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
left: 4px;
}
```